# updating labels asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `<asp:Label ID="ceckSlide"/>` in my aspx page and would like to update this label constantly form a class in my model so that the label keeps changing based on a `for` loop. I would like to know if this is possible, if so how would I go about doing this,

As can be seen from the pseudo-code, I am calling the `add services` method in the aspx page, and would like to update the table in accordance with the for loop in `createServices` class.

class CreateServices

```
private int number = 0
priavte int numbercount = 0;

public void addservices()
{
   numbercount = services.count;

   for(int i = 0;i<service.count;i++)
   {
      ///add services 
      number = i+1;
   }
}

public int GetNumber()
{
    int number= number;
    return slide;
}
public int GetSlideCount()
{

    return numberCount;
}
```

defefaul.aspx

```
protected void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var ser =  new CreateServices();
   var addSer = ser.addservices()
}

// label get updated in this method in the aspx file 
protected void GetSlideNumber()
{

    var ser =  new CreateServices();
    int number= ser .GetSlideNumber();
    int numberCount = ser.GetSlideCount() + 1;

    ceckSlide.Text = slide.ToString() +" Of "+slideCount;
 }
```

Comment: The client requests a page, not the server updates the client.

Comment: Could you include more code and explain what exactly you would like to achieve?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, not necessarily true, see [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) :)

Comment: I have added more detail

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you is to put your label in an UpdatePanel (AJAX) and place a client-side timer (javascript) in your page that sends an update request every few seconds (or whatever you wish). On the server-side, simply update your Model asynchronously and the function that updates the label value should read from the Model directly. Hope that helps.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732553/how-can-i-have-an-ascx-postback-and-refresh-itself-automatically-every-x-seconds?rq=1

Comment: that didnt really help becuase i still dont understand it, will this work in conjuntion with thw for loop

Comment: Add more detail to your question. We don't know what your label is displaying, where is it getting updated and what's the role of your for loop in all this.

Comment: is that enough detil that i am giving you

Comment: +1 @user2061088 - If you want a "live" table in the client's browser (where the user is able to see the updates in "real time"), then this is a good suggestion on how to approach the problem. SO isn't meant to be a code exchange site, so this likely the best answer you'll get.

Comment: @user2061088: Don't take me wrong, but the new detail you have added has made it even more confusing for me. And how do u choose variable names?! Two global vars, one named number and the other numbercount :)! As if number and count were not one and the same thing. And as if all of that was not enough, u type it all in small case. And above all that, u use local vars that have same names as global vars. :D

My sincere advice for you is to see a few good articles about the HTTP protocol and .NET AJAX. You'll find that what you need is easier than you thought.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [PokeIn Library - ASP.NET WebSocket & Comet Ajax Library (Reverse Ajax - Server Push)](http://pokein.codeplex.com/).

From the [documentation webpage](http://www.pokein.com/Help/Documentation.aspx):

> ... PokeIn generates dynamic JavaScript codes from a .NET class to let
>   you call them like you are calling a method from same side.

Comment: I think that more obfuscation of the Request/Response cycle doesn't do any good for someone who doesn't seem to understand it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you don't quite understand how the HTTP protocol works. HTTP uses a Request/Response model, where the client (typically a web browser) makes a request and then the server responds.

The typical architecture used when implementing the auto-updating feature you are describing is exactly what @dotNET has described - the client-side page has some bit of javascript which automatically fires off a request at set intervals. The server responds with the updated state. You can make this interval as small as you'd like, though shorter intervals will sometimes cause problems for users with either slow machines or slow internet connections.

While a simple web application can be developed without much knowledge of the Request/Response cycle, more advanced development (like what you are describing) practically requires that you have a thorough understanding of the web's architecture. If you don't understand the HTTP protocol, I recommend that you take some time to learn it - the small investment will pay huge dividends in how effective and effecient your code will be. [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) is a good place to start because its recommendations adhere most closely to the HTTP specification.